# How i can call some functions when user in raw_input in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How i can run codes ( for e.g print('hello, world') ) when user in raw_input("Enter your value")?

I just want run some codes when user writing input from raw_input function.
For e.g when you are typing your message in chat room, you can see messages of other users also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw_input` is blocking.  You would need to use multiple threads or processes to make that work, and any `print`-like output would clobber what you were writing on the same line.  If you wanted to make a chatroom-like experience, I wouldn't recommend it.  You could try curses if you wanted to stay in terminal-land.